# How to locate and view detailed Heroku log files?

Tags: heroku

My Heroku app is not running. When I view the log files on the website, there is a reference to what I believe is a different more detailed log file.

I connected to Heroku via bash and tried to traverse to the ".npm/" directory, but it does not exist. Where do I find this log file?

```
2018-02-11T20:36:51.615923+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-02-11T20_36_51_610Z-debug.log
2018-02-11T20:36:51.615844+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing '[heroku logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages#debugging)' command inside your project's root directory.

Comment: That was it! Thanks.